# Storing id (or other data) in <option>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with a list of options. To user is displayed user friendly name, however in system I work with id's.

I am thinking of a solution with dinamically denerated select element id's (see example), as I form everything via php and it's not a problem to make id look like "select_opt_"+id in database. Do you know may be more efficient way to use "option" like (id_non_visible => shown_name_visible)?

Example:

```
    <select>
     <option id='select_opt_1'>Data 1</option>
     <option id='select_opt_2'>Data 2</option>
     <option id='select_opt_3'>Data 3</option>
     <option id='select_opt_4'>Data 4</option>
     <option id='select_opt_5'>Data 5</option>
   </select>
```

So my question is, is there more elegant and common way to store additional data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just rely on `value` property. That's what it was made for:

```
   <select>
     <option value="1">Data 1</option>
     <option value="2">Data 2</option>
     <option value="3">Data 3</option>
     <option value="4">Data 4</option>
     <option value="5">Data 5</option>
   </select>
```

Also, `value`'s value will get posted when the form that contains the select is submitted.

Cheers